# Generating and saving many subplot figures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an example of how I generate figures each containing 2 subplots (I have to generate hundreds):

```
figure

axes('Position',[left1 bottom1 width1 height1]);
for i = 1:3:15
... code to generate upper figure
end 

axes('Position',[left2 bottom2 width2 height2]);
for j = 5:9
... code to generate bottom figure
end
```

According to the 'for' loops, I should obtain 5 figures like the one down, but I only get one (the last one) and I really don't know why:

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to optimize my code to generate all the figures and also save them as .png or .jpg?

Comment: If performance is a requirement, I suggest taking a look at the "savepng" contribution on the File Exchange. It's a LOT faster than using the saveas function.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40384-savepng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you need.

If you want Upper Images and Bottom Images in 2 separate figures:

```
f1 = figure();
count = 1;   %Temporary value 
axes('Position',[left1 bottom1 width1 height1]);
for i = 1:3:15
    subplot(1,5,count);
....code to generate upper figure
    count = count+1;
end 

f2 = figure();
count = 1;   %Temporary value 
axes('Position',[left2 bottom2 width2 height2]);
for j = 5:9
    subplot(1,5,count);
....code to generate bottom figure
    count = count+1;
end 
saveas(f1, 'image1.png');
saveas(f2, 'image2.png');
```

If you want Upper Images and Bottom Images in same figure:

```
f1 = figure();
count = 1;   %Temporary value 
axes('Position',[left1 bottom1 width1 height1]);
for i = 1:3:15
    subplot(2,5,count);
....code to generate upper figure
    count = count+1;
end 

count = 6;   %Temporary value 
axes('Position',[left2 bottom2 width2 height2]);
for j = 5:9
    subplot(2,5,count);
....code to generate bottom figure
    count = count+1;
end 
saveas(f1, 'image.png');
```

If you only need one Upper Image and Bottom Image in one figure:

```
a = 1:3:15;
b = 5:9;
for k = 1:5
    f = figure(k);
    subplot(2,1,1);
    axes('Position',[left1 bottom1 width1 height1]);
    i = a(k);
    ... code to generate upper figure  

    subplot(2,1,2);
    axes('Position',[left2 bottom2 width2 height2]);
    j = b(k);
    ... code to generate bottom figure

    print('-dpng','-r800',sprintf('image%d.png',k));
end
```

Comment: Your solution helps running all the upper and bottom figures (contained in the subplot example I provided above), but I get 5 evolving upper figures in one subplot figure, and 5 evolving bottom figures in a separate subplot figure. I just want 1 upper figure and 1 bottom figure in a subplot figure evolving inside the loop.

Comment: you want two subplots in one figure. totally how many figures you want? question isn't clear

Comment: Yes, this what I want. Sorry for not making more clear. I want 5 figures each containing 2 subplots (1 upper image and 1 bottom image). So, almost there. With the last code I get one single figure with 5 upper images and 5 bottom images evolving. I want to split into 5 figures

Comment: Edited for 5 figures. 2 subplot in each. let me know if it works or if you have a problem

Comment: I get 5 figures with the same upper and bottom images, being frozen. I want 5 figures containing 1 upper image and 1 bottom image changing with every iteration.

Comment: Then the problem is within the code you use for generating image i hope.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this before running the last code you proposed. Now the subplots in the figures evolve with every iteration. I only get the handle for each subplot in the background. I fixed that though. Thanks a lot, now everything works. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh, by the way.. `a[k]` and `b[k]` are invalid in Matlab, so I replaced them with `a(k)` and `b(k)`. And to save the figures as .png I did `print('-dpng','-r800',sprintf('image%d.png',k))`. Because I got an error with `saveas(f,['image.png',num2str(k)]);`.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.. i don't have matlab in the system from which i wrote the answer.. so i couldn't test the code

Comment: Also, I got a background handle for each subplot in the figures. So, I removed it by adding `axis(handle1, 'off')` at subplot 1, and `axis(handle2, 'off')` at subplot 2.

Answer (score 4):

Try writing the following pseudocode into your Matlab structure:

```
for count = 1:number_of_figures

figure(count);

axes('Position',[left1 bottom1 width1 height1]);
for i = 1:3:15
    subplot(2,1,1);
... code to generate upper figure
end 

axes('Position',[left2 bottom2 width2 height2]);
for j = 5:9
    subplot(2,1,2);
... code to generate bottom figure

end 

saveas(gcf,'.png');

end
```

To save images in matlab use [`saveas`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html), which also allows you to specify the format (.jpg, .png, etc.).

Comment: I already tried to put the `figure` statement inside the loops, but I only get the individual figures, not the entire subplots.

Comment: Could you elaborate; what do you mean by "entire subplots"? Do you want to store each subplot separately?

Comment: I mean both the upper and the bottom figures in the same subplot figure. With the `figure` statement inside the loops, it only runs the upper and bottom figures separately.

Comment: you will probably need an outer loop for this (if I understand your question correctly). I will edit the answer

Comment: Thank you. I tried other several things as well, but didn't get the desired result.

Comment: It's still not working. Now I only get 5 identical subplot figures. Meaning, instead of obtaining 5 subplot figures evolving inside the loop, like `fig.1=subplot1`, `fig.2=subplot2`, `fig.3=subplot3`, `fig4=subplot4`, `fig5=subplot5`, I get `fig.1=subplot5`, `fig.2=subplot5`, `fig.3=subplot5`, `fig4=subplot5`, `fig5=subplot5`.

Comment: It would help if you would edit and expand your question with exactly what you are trying to do and exactly what your (current) output is